# Interactive broker commissions for a Canadian trading US and Canadian options

Tags: canada, options, interactive-brokers

What commission will I be charged if I trade US options from Canada using Interactive Brokers ?

Details of my question below :

---

**My question has 2 scenarios**

1. Options for Stocks
2. Options for ETFs

For both the scenarios : I trade less than 10,000 contracts a month with another broker (combined)

- Will I be charged the commissions for US securities(which is lower) and has 3 tiers based on the price of the option premium ? [IB site link](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=commission&p=options1) 
  Here is the screenshot of the table from IB's webpage : [IB Table for US option commissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqZjR.png)
- Or will I be charged the Canadian commission even though I will trade US securities.  Here is the image of their Canadian commissions :[IB table for Canadian option commisions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6JRp.png)

Answer (score 1):

Commissions at Interactive Brokers are based on the market you are trading not where you trade from.  The basic rates are:

$ 0.005 USD/share for US stocks 
$ 0.010 CAD/share for CAD stocks.

Minimum commission is 1$.

These rates do not include exchange fees. The commission may be lower if you are adding liquidity and/or you are on their unbundled pricing structure.  The same holds true for option commissions.

Cumulative volume on both markets contributes to the sliding scale commission rate.